# iPhone App finds and loads image not inside .app

Tags: iphone

I've taken an existing iPhone app, and stripped it down to become a "New App" starter project. It has a loading screen, which references an image called "Loading_Background.png". But when I go to the .app and do "Show Package Contents", I don't see any image with this name. There isn't an image with this name in the Copy Bundle Resources in the project, either.

How is the iPhone finding and loading this non-existent image? Is it somehow finding that image in the original application which is installed on the same iPhone?

Comment: Delete the application from the phone, select Xcode, click "Clean all Targets" and re-build. Sounds like some files weren't deleted from the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a clean build (and also delete the app off the iphone) sounds like you are getting something from a past build.

Comment: Ah, ok. I had to delete the App off the phone. Apparently when it uploads the version, it doesn't do a full sync of the .app director. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.  If you keep the same Bundle ID, your iPhone can confuse the two apps.